# Memory Leak in Android App Using AsyncTask to Download File

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I am having an issue with an apparent memory leak while using the AsyncTask class. The Android class below is intended to download an image from http and store it into the member variable "**Drawable bgImageDrawable**". The function that begins the download process is **downloadBackgroundImage()** . After this is run, it appears that the Used Memory size increases by 8MB each time. I am downloading a jpeg image file that is 800KB, but I am not sure why the Memory increases significantly. Is there an issue with the code below?

```
public class Example 
{
    private URL bgImageUrl;
    private Drawable bgImageDrawable;

    public Example(String bg)   {
        try {
            this.setBgImageUrl(new URL(bg));
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url, String srcName) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException  {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), srcName);
    }

    public void downloadBackgroundImage()    {
        new DownloadFilesTask().execute(getBgImageUrl().toString());
    }

    public void setBgImageDrawable(Drawable bgImageDrawable) {
        this.bgImageDrawable = bgImageDrawable;
    }

    public URL getBgImageUrl() {
        return bgImageUrl;
    }
    public void setBgImageUrl(URL bgImageUrl) {
        this.bgImageUrl = bgImageUrl;
    }

    /* The purpose of this class is to download a file asynchronously. */
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> 
    {
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... s)       {
            Drawable bgImage = null;
              try  {
                    bgImage = drawableFromUrl(s[0], "src name");
                    return bgImage;
              } 
              catch (MalformedURLException e)             {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              } 
              catch (IOException e)               {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }

            return bgImage;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)        {

         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result)       {
             setBgImageDrawable(result);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: By saying "increases by 8MB each time" do you mean the memory only increases once every time you run the code from scratch? Or the memory usage keeps increasing after you loaded the jpg, while the code is still running?

Comment: This link should help you. http://rcs34-android.blogspot.com/2012/09/memory-leak-when-setting-drawable-from.html

Comment: Hi @StoneBird. By 8MB each time, the current app's memory usage increases 8MB after downloading the image. If I download it twice, it will be 16MB, 24MB, 32MB, etc. I'm using Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime() to get the used memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert 800KB jpeg to a drawable. Your jpeg after downloading decoded to a bitmap. And the bitmap is wraped inside Drawable. So it's ok that decoded bitmap of 800KB jpeg takes 8MB.

You can use profiler to see what exactly taking so much memory. IMHO it's a drawable.